# Polynomial change of LED brightness

Tags: arduino

I try to change the brightness of an LED following the formula in `out1`. I'm pretty sure that something is going wrong because it doesn't really change its brightness and it never stops lightening. It should basically do the same than a sin wave but instead of the sin I try to use my equation!

```cpp
const int LED = 11;
const int LED1 = 10;
const int LED2 = 9;

void setup()
{
}

void loop()
{
  float in1, out1, out2, out3;

for (in1 = 0; in1 < 10; in1++)
{
out1 = 8.8 * pow(10,-4) * pow(in1,4) - 0.0034 * pow(in1,3) +0.37 * pow(in1,2) -6.7 *in1 +1.7 *pow(10,2);
//out2 = 1.207*pow(in1,4)-0.0011*pow(in1,3)+0.16*pow(in1,2)-5.5*in1+2,0763;
//out3 = 4.829*pow(in1,4)-0.034*pow(in1,3)+0.37*pow(in1,2)-6.7*in1+2,076;

analogWrite(LED,out1);
//delay(1);
//analogWrite(LED1,out2);
//analogWrite(LED2,out3);

}

analogWrite(LED,LOW);

/*analogWrite(LED,out1);
analogWrite(LED1,out2);
analogWrite(LED2,out3);
//analogWrite(LED1,LOW);*/
delay(500);
```

Comment: Also check out the [graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=8.8e-4+*+x^4+-+0.0034+*+x^3+%2B+0.37+*+x^2+-+6.7+*+x+%2B+1.7e2,+x+%3D+0+to+10) of your function - I'm not sure that within the output range of 140-170 one could see a difference in LED brightness.

Comment: That could be possible but how do I have to manipulate my function so that I can see differences. I'm also wondering why it never stops lightening.

Comment: are out1, out2 and out3 connected to the three pins of an RGB LED?

Comment: @lkdhruw I've asked some "software only" questions in the Arduino stack exchange and gotten a cold reaction.  Since this is programming-related I think it's okay to have it here.

Answer (score 1):

Even though your loop uses floating-point, in human terms, it's still going to run very fast.  Suggest a delay after each change to start with.

```
for (in1 = 0; in1 < 10; in1++)
{
    out1 = 8.8 * pow(10,-4) * pow(in1,4) - 0.0034 * pow(in1,3) +0.37 * pow(in1,2) -6.7 *in1 +1.7 *pow(10,2);
    analogWrite(LED,out1);
    delay(2000);
}
```

If this is an RGB led and we're just changing the value on one pin, with a delay that is noticeable to the human eye you might see a small change here.  Though apparent brightness of 170 vs 140 still might be hard to discern.